# Keyboard shortcuts "block" all combinations that involve those keys

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 with GNOME. I am facing an issue of keyboard combinations blocking all other combinations that involve those keys. For example, in Firefox, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> doesn't open private window like it should, but instead opens the print window, because I'm using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> for something else.

This is not an isolated incident, it happens in other applications as well.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, both in terms of posting and solving the problem @pomsky!

You're a life saver.

@N0rbert's answer worked beautifully for me :)